# Using include in Julia and global variables

Tags: julia

Say I have some Julia module `main` in a single file "main.jl"

```
module main

export tester,add
a=1

function hi()
    return "hi"
end

function tester()
    return hi()
end

function add()
    return a+1
end
    
end
```

Now suppose I want to break up this into two files, with one including auxiliary functions like `hi()`, like so:

```
module auxillary

function hi()
    return "hi"
end
end
```

and use `include` to copy/paste the functions in auxillary.jl in the main file:

```
module main

include("auxillary.jl")
export add,tester

a=1

function tester()
    return hi()
end
function add()
    return a+1
end

end
```

Then calling `tester()` from main gives an error "`hi()` not defined". Is `include` not enough or do I also have to use `using`?

Secondly, suppose I wanted to move `add()` to auxillary.jl, but keep the global variable `a` in main.jl. And then I will call `add()` from main.jl. How would I do this?

Comment: just do not define `module auxillary` as it seems you do not need a separate module. Files and modules are orthogonal concepts in Julia, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#modules.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I am working on a much more complicated projected and have only given a simple example above of my problem. My code is very long and I want to split it into files for readability. Are you saying in the file auxillary.jl defining module is not necessary? Is ""include" equivalent to copy/pasting and doesn't do anything else?

Comment: It is almost like copy-paste. The biggest difference is that it additionally sets task-local include path (but it is a difference that is rarely relevant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code layout you need is the following:

```
module MyModule

# this is equal to do doing `include` here
module Auxillary
function hi()
   return "hi"
end
function add()
   return Main.MyModule.a+1
end
end

export add,tester

using Main.MyModule.Auxillary

a=1
function tester()
   return Auxillary.hi()
end

end
```

This can be run as:

```
julia> using Main.MyModule

julia> MyModule.Auxillary.add()
2

julia> MyModule.tester()
"hi"
```

#### Explanation

Each `module` creates its namespace so the trick to get it running is to properly point out which namespace you need.
When this code is run in the console, the modele `MyModule` becomes a submodule of `Main` and `Auxillary` is a submodule of `MyModule`.

Comment: is it acceptable to just use include("auxillary.jl") but not use the keyword "module" in auxillary.jl? Are there downsides/dangers to doing this?

Comment: This is just a decision on code layout. Usually you have one module with many `include`s and the included files do not have submodules. Contrary to other languages it is not obligatory for each file to contain a module. Look for an example at https://github.com/pszufe/SimpleHypergraphs.jl/blob/master/src/SimpleHypergraphs.jl (or some other small package) This is a very typical package layout in Julia.